# Automatically run both mypy AND pylint at every save?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I figured out how to run `pylint` when saving my file in VSCode, but I don't like the fact that I'm forced to decide between `pylint` and `mypy` when I want both. Is there a way I can force VSCode to combine warnings from `pylint` and a type checker?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a setup that worked for me:

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyArgs": [
        "--ignore-missing-imports",
        "--follow-imports=silent",
        "--show-column-numbers",
        "--strict"
    ],
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/d33tah/virtualenv/bin/python"
}
```

It looks like I had to explicitly enable both linters and add `--strict` so that it works the way I want it to.

Comment: in order to edit (and paste) the above code in VSCode, press `shift`+`command`+`p` and then type "user settings (JSON)". Source https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:~:text=You%20can%20open%20the%20settings,to%20using%20the%20default%20values.

Comment: also, if you've been using other vscode commands to change your settings, there is a possibility that the commands have updated your `.vscode/settings.json` (workspace settings) within your project.