# Configure Mypy in VSCode to enforce type hinting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, mypy

I want to configure Mypy on Visual Studio Code to enforce type hinting in my project.

I use the following configuration

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=W0611"
    ],
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled":true,
    "python.linting.mypyCategorySeverity.note":"Warning",
    "python.linting.mypyArgs": [

        "--ignore-missing-imports",
        "--follow-imports=silent",
        "--show-column-numbers",
        "--disallow-untyped-defs=True",
        "--disallow-untyped-calls=True",
        "--check-untyped-defs=True",
        "--no-implicit-optional=True",

    ]
```

However I have some functions with no type annotations and I do not get any info, warning or errors about them.
Actually Mypy doesn't seem to work. It actually only catches false-positive when I remove the "no-implicit-optional" option.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Could you please provide us with specific examples that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Let's say I had a bunch of non-annotated functions for example:

def do_something(a,b):
     xxxxxx

And I was expecting mypy to report the issue in the problems section of VS Code but it wasn't.

I got it to work though now let me add a reply.

Answer (score 14):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220416/automatically-run-both-mypy-and-pylint-at-every-save/57221283#57221283), and then realized my mistake. Adding the "=True" in the mypyArgs was wrong.

Here are my new settings :

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
 
        "--disable=W0611"
    ],
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.mypyCategorySeverity.error":"Warning",
    "python.linting.mypyArgs": [
        "--ignore-missing-imports",
        "--follow-imports=silent",
        "--show-column-numbers",
        "--disallow-untyped-defs",
        "--disallow-untyped-calls"
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The new approach is to simply install the Microsoft-provided extension, and the above settings that you can customize per project are now different, e.g. instead of "python.linting.mypyArgs", you would provide "mypy-type-checker.args".

See here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.mypy-type-checker